# Regenerate all designer.cs files in a project webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5

I recently upgraded my webforms project to .net 4.5.

I need to regenerate all designer.cs files of aspx and ascx pages. I can do this if i take them one by one and save them, but i need a method that automatically does this for me in the entire project, since it is a very large project and i have alot of .aspx and .ascx files.

Is there any way to do this?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In what way do you need to regenerate them? What do you want to change in them?

Comment: I switched from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5 and by saving the file the .designer.cs is regenerated accordingly. The issue is that I need to this for thousands of files. Thx

Comment: It's just that... I never *had* to regenerate them when changing framework versions. It's just that when it *is* saved again it changes the version number of the generator in a comment at the top..

Answer (score 0):

Right click your application and click on "convert to web application". It is supposed to regenerate your designer.cs files.